# Warning about overriden methods when using a mixin

Tags: templates, d, overriding

I'd like to use a mixin to implement an interface. This works fine until I subclass. The problem is that the mixin template also implement an template function.

Something like:

```
interface Features {
    void feature1();
    void feature2();
}

mixin template FeaturesImplementer() {
    int bar;
    final void feature1(){}
    void feature2(){}
    void typeStuff(T)(){}
}

class WithFeature: Features {
    mixin FeaturesImplementer;
    this(){typeStuff!(typeof(this));}
}

class AlsoWithFeature: WithFeature {
    mixin FeaturesImplementer;
    this(){typeStuff!(typeof(this));}
}

void main() {
    new WithFeature;
    new AlsoWithFeature;
}
```

outputs:

> Error: function AlsoWithFeature.FeaturesImplementer!().feature1 cannot override final function WithFeature.FeaturesImplementer!().feature1
>
> Deprecation: implicitly overriding base class method WithFeature.FeaturesImplementer!().feature2 with AlsoWithFeature.FeaturesImplementer!().feature2 deprecated; add 'override' attribute
>
> Error: mixin AlsoWithFeature.FeaturesImplementer!() error instantiating

I could put `typeStuff` in another template but the problem is that in `FeaturesImplementer` everything goes together. Even the integer is used by the features. Is there a way to always use the same mixin with everuthing inside ?

Comment: Why are you mixing it into the child class too? It will be inherited from the base class without that...

Comment: because otherwise typestuff() dont work. It contains code that work on `this`, if not remixed, this is always of the same type where the template has been mixed.

Comment: Ah, the language has an answer for that though: http://dlang.org/template#TemplateThisParameter

Comment: Well, your problem is the final method. It just does not make sense to put a final method in a mixing that will be used like you do in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this work with a bit of static checking, using the [`static if`](http://dlang.org/version.html#staticif) expression, which evaluates at compile time. The idea is to verify if the implementation is already here, using the traits, particularly [`hasMember`](http://dlang.org/traits.html#hasMember).

You'll also have to check using std.traits if it's the first time that the template is mixed, in your example it's equivalent to check if the ancestor (Object) is already a Feature.

For example:

```
interface Features {
    void feature1();
    void feature2();
}

mixin template FeaturesImplementer() {

    import std.traits: BaseClassesTuple;
    alias C = typeof(this);
    enum OlderHave = is(BaseClassesTuple!C[0] : Features);
    enum Have = is(C : Features);
    enum Base = Have & (!OlderHave);

    static if (Base || !__traits(hasMember, C, "bar"))
    int bar;

    static if (Base || !__traits(hasMember, C, "feature1"))
    final void feature1(){}

    static if (Base || !__traits(hasMember, C, "feature2"))
    void feature2(){}

    void typeStuff(T)(){}
}

class WithFeature: Features {
    mixin FeaturesImplementer;
    this(){typeStuff!(typeof(this));}
}

class AlsoWithFeature: WithFeature {
    mixin FeaturesImplementer;
    this(){typeStuff!(typeof(this));}
}

void main() {
    new WithFeature;
    new AlsoWithFeature;
}
```

The different function implementations are then only *mixed* if not already there.

Note that there was also a hidden problem  in your original code due to the int field being redeclared, depending on the way you casted an instance, the field might be the one of `WithFeature` or `AlsoWithFeature`, but I don't know why the compiler did not complain about that.

Comment: Yeah, this is an answer to the question, but I think a solution to the problem is to just use a template this parameter in that one method then don't mix it into the child classes again.

Comment: Actually i already know static things a bit. @AdamD.Ruppe, the problem is pointer is not on -this- variable, pointer is on result of trait getMember, but trait get Member already used the good type (T) ?

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe: if you're interested, you can check [this Dlang NG question](http://forum.dlang.org/post/pczicdlosfilqwuhkdsu@forum.dlang.org), if think that the real problem is better explained.